# System of distinct representative professors and students problem

Tags: combinatorics

So I was doing exercises from a Combinatorics textbook.  I ran into this problem.

Suppose we have $n$ students, $s_1,s_2,\dots,s_n,$ and $n$ professors, 
$p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n$.  For each student $s_i$ we define a set of his/her favorite professors, $S_i$. Every student has at most $f$ favorite professors (where $f\geq 3$), while each professor $p_j$ appears in at least $f$ sets $S_{j_1},S_{j_2},\dots,S_{j_f}$.

For a given value of $f$, let $\pi_i (f)$ be the number of appearances of professor $p_i$ on the students' lists, and $\sigma_j (f)= |S_j|$.

$1.$ What is $\operatorname{max}\{\pi_i(f)| 1\leq i\leq n\}$ and
$\operatorname{min}\{\sigma_j(f)| 1\leq j\leq n\}$ for a fixed value of $f$? Note that you are not looking  the max or min over the whole range of values of $f$, but rather for any given value, and the range is all values of $i$. So, your answer is a function of $f$

$2.$ Every student needs three letters of recommendation. Can they select their favorite professors for the letters so that no professor writes more than three letters? Prove your claim or show a counter-example.

How would you solve this?  I recognize that this is a system of distinct representatives kind of problem.  But somehow I can't think of a way to find a solution.  Please help!